# UIAlertController image

Tags: swift, spritekit

Как в UIAlertController добавить картинку?

```html
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "My Image:", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        
        alertController.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 90.0, green: 70.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 0.1)
        alertController.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { action in
            let scene = ProgressScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")!
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.3))
            })
        
        self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: добавить картинку самому UIAlertController вроде как нельзя, есть вариант добавить картинку к UIAlertAction. устроит такое?

Comment: а нет, можно. не могу понять, как расширить весь контроллер, чтоб картинка была нормально расположена в лэйауте

Comment: Я пытаюсь ей хотя бы размер задать

Comment: если ей задать размер, получится примерно вот такое: (смотрите позицию звездочки) http://i.stack.imgur.com/0v2UU.png

Comment: Разобралась, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myAlertImage")
var action = UIAlertAction(title: "title", style: .Default, handler: nil)
action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
alertController.addAction(action)
```

Comment: А как этой картинке изменить размер? Так не получается: image!.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)

Comment: @Leci Посмотрите здесь https://gist.github.com/tomasbasham/10533743 или http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966885/ios-swift-resize-image-to-200x200pt-px

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: @Leci ссылка на so в комменте выше показывает как сделать ресайз