# UIAlertController image (2)

Tags: swift, spritekit

Ранее задавала вопрос [UIAlertController image](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529507/uialertcontroller-image) как добавить в картинку, она добавилась, но почему-то она полностью синяя, можно ли как-то вообще убрать стиль?

```html
let image = UIImage(named: "myAlertImage")
var action = UIAlertAction(title: "title", style: .Default, handler: nil)
action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
alertController.addAction(action)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам надо задать `renderingMode.AlwaysOriginal`. Его можно задавать только при инициализации, так что делайте примерно так

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myAlertImage")
image = image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
var action = UIAlertAction(title: "title", style: .Default, handler: nil)
action.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
alertController.addAction(action)
```

Comment: не знала о таком, спасибо)